# Highlight the jquery tab when error occured validate with jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, validation

I have a form with 3 tabs using jquery UI/TABS. im using jquery validation plugin to validate the form and if my 2nd tab's text box hit the  required  field error how to highlight the 2nd tab then user can see the where is the error coming from

any help

regards

Answer (score 2):

Just find the second tab and add some css class to it.

Given you've created tabs like this:

```
$("#example").tabs();
```

You can easily "select" any of the tabs and add some class to it to highlight it (to add class to third tab:

```
$("#example > ul > li:nth-child(3)").addClass('my_tab_highlight');
```

Of course you have to have some css to correspond with the my_tab_highlight css class, to have any visuall indication. Also, after user clicks this third tab you would probably want to remove the my_tab_highlight class.

Comment: i can add the css to tab problem is in which event i call to addClass ?

Comment: Depends on which jquery validation plugin are you using.